# /dev/mapper/cryptsetup1 is not ready yet or not present, slow system

Tags: encryption, upstart, swap, troubleshooting, init

Today I had a very high system load because I used many applications at the same time (VirtualBox, totem, firefox,...). The load was so high, that the system almost didn't react anymore. Then I killed VirtualBox and the system became a bit faster, however it was terrible slow compared to the usual behaviour though I killed all large applications. After a reboot I got the message:

/dev/mapper/cryptsetup1 is not ready yet or not present, slow system

However the system works but very very slow.

I tried to disable and reenable encrypted swap as described here: http://www.logilab.org/29155

Now the error message is missing but the system is still very very slow.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Check your kernel log at `/var/log/kern.log`. What storage medium do you have? A SSD or HDD?

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug in the boot process of Ubuntu, probably in mountall or some upstart job.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).